# filled dependent picklist in test class

Tags: unit-test

How to fill dependent picklist field in test class.
my field from object Contract_Order__c  is Starter_Kit_Pack__c which has two value 'Light Pack  ' and ',Medium Pack'.the controlling field of this field is Pricing_Model__c which has values 'Bass Plan' , 'Bundle Plan' , 'Device Fee' , 'Starter Kit'.

TEST CLASS

```
@isTest
public  class ContractOrderTriggerHandler_test {

    Public  Testmethod Static void testContract(){

       Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = 'Lee Enterprise, Inc';
        acc.Tax_Applicable__c = true;
        acc.Tax_Rate__c = 7.00;
        insert acc;

        Zone__c zone = new Zone__c();
        zone.Name = 'Asia-Pacific';
        zone.Currency_Code__c='SGD';
        insert zone;

        Price_Book__c pb1 = new Price_Book__c();
        pb1.Name = 'Test Sigfox';
        pb1.Product_Type__c = 'Sigfox';
        pb1.Start_Date__c = system.today()+3;
        insert pb1;

        MSA__c ms = new MSA__c();
        ms.Customer_Name__c = acc.id;
        ms.Pricing_Model__c = 'Bass plan';
        insert ms;

     Contract_Order__c cOrder = new Contract_Order__c();
        cOrder.Sigfox_Contract_ID__c='SIGFOX001';
        cOrder.MSA__c = ms.id;
        cOrder.Zone__c = zone.id;       
        cOrder.Status__c = UnaBizConstants.ContractOrderActiveStatus;
        cOrder.Automatic_Renewal__c = true;
        cOrder.Auto_Renewed__c = false;
        cOrder.Primary_Contract_Order__c = null;
        cOrder.Contract_Name__c='SIGFOX001';
        cOrder.RecordtypeId=Schema.SObjectType.Contract_Order__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Unabell').getRecordTypeId();
        //cOrder.Customer_Name__c=ac.Id;
        //cOrder.Status__c='Active';
         cOrder.Start_Date__c=System.today();
        //cOrder.Next_Renewal_Date__c = system.today().addMonths(integer.valueOf(System.Label.Unbell_Renewal_Before_Month));
        //cOrder.Sigfox_Subscription_Plan__c='Silver';
        cOrder.Price_Book__c=pb1.Id;
        cOrder.of_Devices__c=8000;
        cOrder.Volume_Tranche_PL__c='> 1000 and <= 10000';
        cOrder.Pricing_Model__c = 'Starter Kit';
        cOrder.Order_Country__c='Singapore';
        cOrder.Currency_ISO_Code__c='SGD';
        cOrder.Discount_Order_Creation__c=10;
        cOrder.Discount_Activation__c=10;
        cOrder.Unit_Rate__c = 12.0;
        cOrder.Starter_Kit_Pack__c='Medium Pack';//ERROR LINE: bad picklist value

        cOrder.Discount_Rate__c=10.0;
        insert cOrder;

      Invoice__c inv = new Invoice__c();
        //inv.MSA__c = ms.id;
        inv.Customer__c = acc.id;
        inv.Contract_ID__c = cOrder.id;
        insert inv;

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your controller code here that will us to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is simply, "The same way you populate any other field". That is,

```
myRecord.myField__c = 'myValue';
```

The Controlling field (and the picklist values allowed for each value of the controlling field) is simply a UI construct. There is no inherent system validation that takes place to force the dependent picklist to take one of the "approved" values, it's simply there to restrict values *shown* to the user when they edit a record.